# send() with linux socket crashing my program / server over localhost

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, network-programming, localhost

I have written a relatively simple server application that handles GET requests and serves static pages over the internet to a web browser from a desktop computer.

It works fine over the internet but when I am testing on localhost I find that it crashes in a particular situation.

On a new connection it will often crash, but only if it has already been previously connected.

In other words if I open localhost in my browser it will serve up the index page as expected.

If I then click return in the browser search bar again loading in localhost it will crash, a very high percentage of the time, and yet this never happens when I server pages over the internet via port 80.

The index page itself dynamically loads in other pages, some through html tags such as   and  and some using XMLHttpRequest through $().load.

I wonder if there is any particular difference between how the request is routed on localhost and on port 80 that may explain this problem?

Otherwise my code is fairly complex but the crash happens on the actual call to :

```
ssize_t bytesSent = send(fd, message, size, 0);
```

I have done numerous tests to make sure that the fd is ok and that changes to size and message are not causing the crash and I can't find any problems. For example if the size of the file is wrong it won't crash the server simple give unexpected behaviour and I carefully checked how the fd was being generated that it wasn't making errors there.

The code around the call looks like this:

```
int TcpSocket::doSend(const char* message, int fd, size_t size) const
{
    if (fd == 0)
    {
        fd = mFiledes;
    }

    size = (size == 0) ? strlen(message) : size;
    ssize_t bytesSent = send(fd, message, size, 0);

    if (bytesSent < 1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think if I post too much code on here it may start to be confusing and I think the key to the issue is how the loop back interface works, and am hoping that someone more experienced with server programming and Linux will have something jump out at them, but if you want to see all the code the full project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/samredway/sserv) and the relevant files will be Server.cpp and in the separate ssocks repo TcpSocket.cpp

EDIT / UPDATE :

When I ran the program using the dgb I got this output:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/sam/sserv/bin/sserv 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffef7fe700 (LWP 2169)]
[New Thread 0x7fffeffff700 (LWP 2168)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff4fbf700 (LWP 2167)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff57c0700 (LWP 2166)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5fc1700 (LWP 2165)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff67c2700 (LWP 2164)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff6fc3700 (LWP 2163)]

Program received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff5fc1700 (LWP 2165)]
0x00007ffff76a62ef in __libc_send (fd=5, buf=0x7fffe8003700, n=2219, flags=0)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/send.c:31
31  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/send.c: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Do you use multiple threads in your program? if yes, could it be that you are not locking resources properly, so that one thread reads from a memory location while another threads writes to that location?

Comment: Yes I am running multithreads, but that was also my first suspicion so I ran the server with only one active thread and alas still the same problem...

Comment: It's very unlikely that send() crashes, unless you have corrupted some memory. So, run your program with valgrind and see if it detects anything. Or can run you program in gdb when it crashes (or obtain a coredump), and then print out the stacktrace ?

Comment: Which `doSend` does it crash on? the first one or the second one?

Comment: @nos I have added the output from running it in gdb. I notice the browser just hung with the debugger running though so I think the debugger is altering the programs behaviour. I don't know much about gdb though.

Comment: @JoelC It crashes on the actual line which calls the Linux function send()... I isolated the error to there by using cout to find out where it crashed. I wonder if the browser can cause the crash by closing (not diconecting from but actually closing) the socket while I am trying to write to it? I notice that if I add the line : close(fd); it will cause a crash like this?

Comment: Can you give the output of a `bt` in **gdb** after the crash? This will give the backtrace to determine what the parameters were, etc.

Comment: Actually the info from running in gdb that I posted seems to have the answer. It was as I suspected caused by the browser shutting the connection. Not sure why this causes a SIGPIPE error when connecting on localhost but it seems that when I use the flag MSG_NOSIGNAL with send() to ignore SIGPIPE error my problem is gone. I haven't fully tested yet but I have run refresh in chrome around 60+ times on localhost without a crash. A full explanation of why this should be and how it relates to using the loopback interface would still be interesting.

Comment: @SamRedway By default you get a SIGPIPE if trying to write to a broken TCP connection. That's almost always a bad default, so ignoring SIGPIPE (with signal() or sigaction() ) in a TCP application is common practice , and deal with the error return code from send() instead.